# Sort filenames based on dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a list of dependencies generated by a program in the makefile format i.e.

```
 dependent_resource: dependency1 dependency2
```

However my final programm, which combines these resources actually needs the files in the order of dependencies, i.e. all dependencies have to be supplied before the dependent resource.

Is there any tool, which can use these makefile dependency files and sort the list of resources in order later on to be processed by the compiler?

**EDIT**:

A simple transformation of the dependency files will not work, since I have a dependency file for each resource and dependencies might appear multiple times in the files (as dependencies for different resources).

The best way would most likely be to directly get the dependencies from make itself. It has to have the dependencies available at least implicitely, since it will build the dependencies in the same order I need to supply them later. But I don't know a way to extract them from the running make.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Yes, I know the algorithm very well. However implementing it in GNU Make is not a fun exercise at all. That is, why I am looking for an external tool, which implements the algorithm and the parsing of the dependency files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Make itself. Suppose your dependency file is called `dependencyFile`. Then run this makefile:

```
EVERYTHING := $(shell cat dependencyFile | sed 's/:/ /')

all: $(EVERYTHING)
    @

%:
    @echo $@

include dependencyFile
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work, since I have multiple dependency files and files might be mentioned multiple times in in different files. Also the current command you posted will put the dependent resource before the dependencies. However I need it after the dependencies (that part can easily be fixed by changing the `sed` statement to reorder dependencies).

Comment: @LiKao, you should have mentioned that you had more than one list of dependencies at the outset, but it's easy enough to adapt this method to multiple files. Let's get the other part working first; I've *tested* this, and it prints the dependencies before the "dependent resource". Try it. If we can agree on this then I can edit my answer for multiple files. In what form do you have the list of filenames? (I suspect you have something specific in mind.)

Comment: For me a `echo "dependent_resource: dependency1 dependency2" | sed 's/:/ /'` yields `dependent_resource  dependency1 dependency2` which is the wrong order. As I said though, this is easily fixed using `sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2 \1/'` instead. The list of files is available through some variables within make.

Comment: @LiKao, the *variable* has the files in the same order as in the dependency files, perhaps with repetitions. The *makefile* reports the files in correct order, without repetition. Did you want the list in the form of a makefile variable (and forget to tell us)?

Comment: Ok, I completely misread your answer. Now that I know how this is working I will probably be able to adapt this to multiple files. Thanks for the help and sorry for the hassle.